# The problem with the implicit subject

Tags: grammar

> I have bought the new car while having the serious problems.

My question is : what subject is for "having the serious problems"

How should I interpret the above sentence, as

> I have bought the new car while I had the serious problems.

or

> I have bought the new car while the car had the serious problems.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. All three sentences are ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to *I*, not *the car*.  But you need to correct a few things

1)  use  "bought" (present) or "had bought" (past perfect).  Don't mix present perfect "have bought with progressive "having".

2) drop "the" from "the serious problems" if the problems were mentioned previously, say "those" (if the problems are gone now) or "these" (if the problems continue now)

3) change "the new car" to "a new car" unless the car was mentioned previously.

In short, the simplest unambiguous way

(if you had the problems)
I bought a new car while having serious problems.

to make that explicit, you could add "personal":

I bought a new car while having serious personal problems.

(if the car had the problems)
I bought a new car that had serious problems.

(by the way—was this really a new car? They rarely have serious problems, and if they do, they are usually covered by warranty. Was the car only "new" to you? It seems more likely it was a used car.)

Comment: It was a new car for me, but not a brand new. Thanks @Brian.

Comment: @Brian this was not my question but there is something I want to ask that why we cannot use "having" with present perfect? do you presume that the sentence is "I bought the new car while I WAS having the serious problems." and  how can we call this kind of sentence in grammar terminology? Is it kind of reduced relative clause ?

Comment: The similar question as for "I cleaned my tie to look nice." (I or tie)

Comment: see Jay's answer. He explains the "period of time" discrepancy. Then think about "bought the car WHEN I was having problems" .

Answer (score 1):

First, a more common phrasing would be, "I bought a new car while having serious problems." Your sentence as worded doesn't quite work.

"Have bought" indicates something happening over a period of time. But you wouldn't buy one car over a period of time. So you could say, "I have bought new cars while having serious problems", meaning, there have been a number of occasions when you have done this. If it was only one time, you should use the simple past, "I bought ..."

Normally you would say "a new car" rather than "the new car", because there is probably not a specific new car that must be distinguished from some other car. But it's not impossible. If earlier you had said that you were considering whether to buy a used 2007 Chevy or a new 2014 Ford, you might then say "I decided to buy the new car", as opposed to the used.

Normally you would just say "serious problems" rather than "the serious problems". If you had previously mentioned some specific serious problems and some specific problems that were not serious, you might say "the serious problems" to be clear which set of problems you were talking about. But again, unlikely.

All that said, getting to your question: The normal reading of this sentence would be that "I" was "having serious problems" at the time "I" bought the car. If the car had problems -- if you bought a car whose engine blew up before you got it off the lot of something -- you would say, "I bought a new car that had serious problems". If you were wanted to emphasize that the car had these problems at the time you bought it and not before or after, like you've since fixed the problems perhaps, you could say, "I bought a new car while it was having serious problems." But simply "while having X" would normally be understood to refer back to the subject of the sentence, "I", and not some other noun.